# How to implement swipe gesture on half view and pan gesture on other half view?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How to add a pan gesture to first half (0,0,160,480) of a view and on same view a swipe gesture on (160,0,160,480) as well?

The view is table view and on swiping left the cell content should change and on panning in right the tableview should move like facebook ios app

Comment: Take two Different UIview as SubView of mainView with Required Frame Size then add Desired Gestures.

Comment: I have to do on same view but unable to distinguish between swipe and pan

Comment: @All Please Give the reason while DownVoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take two Different UIview as SubView of mainView with Required Frame Size then add Desired Gestures :-

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeVC:)];
    swipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.subView.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizer];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panVC:)];
    panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeGestureRecognizer];
    [self.subView2.view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

The Below method is called when recognition of a gesture by either gestureRecognizer or otherGestureRecognizer

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The view is table view and on swiping left the cell content should change and on panning in right the tableview should move like facebook ios app

Comment: and why you gave me negative ranking

Comment: @AnuragKabra i didn't downVoted May be some one else.